# Django change password link is not active?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am learning an authentication in Django. Today I am stuck with this problem and I am not able to figure out how can I solve it. I want to make a form for password change. but the change form link is not active and I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def user_change(request):
    current_user = request.user
    form = UserProfileChange(instance = current_user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileChange(request.POST,instance = current_user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = UserProfileChange(instance = current_user)
    form = UserProfileChange(instance = current_user)

    return render(request, 'App_Login/change_profile.html', context={'form':form})

@login_required
def pass_change(request):
    current_user = request.user
    form  = PasswordChangeForm(current_user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(current_user, data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'App_login/pass_change.html', context = {'form':form})
```

here is urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name  = 'App_Login'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name = "signup"),
    path('signin/', views.login_page, name = 'signin'),
    path('logout/' , views.logout_user, name = "logout" ),
    path('profile/' , views.profile, name = "profile" ),
    path('change-profile/' , views.user_change, name = "user_change" ),
    path('password/' , views.pass_change, name = "pass_change" ),

]
```

here is change_profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} change User profile {% endblock %}


{% block body_block %} 

<h2>Change Profile</h2>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <input type="submit" value="Change" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

here is forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email Address", required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email', 'password1', 'password2')


class UserProfileChange(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
```

Comment: Please show `UserProfileChange` and `App_Login/change_profile.html`

Comment: @Alasdair I updated you can checknow

Comment: `UserChangeForm` was designed to be used in the Django admin. It looks like the link is being escaped when you use crispy forms. I can't see a good way to prevent that. I would suggest removing `password` from your `UserChangeForm` form, then updating the `change_profile.html` template to add your own link to the change password page.

Answer (score 0):

Django has an inbuilt functionality to do that in your urls file modify it to according your needs

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
#
# Rest Of Your Code
#
path('password/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='template to render here',
        success_url = 'page to redirect after password is changed'),name='password')
]
```